# Predicting a Numeric value in Future Years

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret, glmnet

I have this data set, and I want to predict number of PTS beyond 2018:

```
Team  PTS   W   GF   GA     S    SA   Year
NSH   88   38  214  233  2382  2365   2014
NSH  104   47  226  202  2614  2304   2015
NSH   96   41  224  213  2507  2231   2016
NSH   94   41  238  220  2557  2458   2017
NSH  117   53  261  204  2641  2650   2018
```

Data dictionary:

```
Team = NHL team (all NSH here)
PTS = total points
W = wins
GF = goals for (goals scored by NSH)
GA = goals against
S = shots
SA = shots against
```

I used the caret package for modeling, and the resulting predictions give pretty good estimates of PTS total for the entire set. I can compare predicted values to the actual values, and it looks pretty good. Here is my model, using CV and the entire data set to predict:

```
caret_m1 <- train(
  PTS ~ W + GF + GA + S + SA, NSH_stats,
  method = "glmnet",
  trControl = trainControl(
    method = "cv", number = 5,
    repeats = 5, verboseIter = TRUE
     )
  )

pred <- predict(caret_m1, NSH_stats)
```

I also used a Train/Test model on the data (my dataset is from 2006 up - here I just used a sample), and I got a slightly higher RMSE when I split the set). **How do I predict PTS total for 2019 and beyond? ** Thanks.

Comment: What is pts, can you explain?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen In the NHL (National Hockey League), when a team wins a game they get 2 points, when they lose they got 0 points, and when they lose in overtime they get 1 point. Each NHL team plays 82 games, and they seed for the playoffs by number of points

Answer (score 0):

To predict $PTS$ for 2019, you first need to forecast the values of $W$, $GF$, $GA$, $S$, and $SA$, as $PTS = f(W, GF, GA, S,SA)$.

Since you only have data from 2006, you can start with simple univariate time-series models like [autoregressive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) $AR(p)$, [moving-average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model) $MA(q)$, and [autoregressive–moving-average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model) $ARMA(p, q)$ for each individual predictor.

If you want to capture the interdependencies among those predictors over time, [vector autoregression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression) is a good option.

Comment: Ah, this answer has led me to datacamp and the forecasting tutorials there... Thank you. Also, my research on the vars package did not seem intuitive, but then again, I am no math/stats major..